# How to change alignment in BootsFaces ? Need last link of navbar to right corner

Tags: css, html, bootsfaces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<b:navBar brand="Brand" brandHref="#" inverse="true">
    <b:navbarLinks>
        <b:navLink value="Home" href="#"></b:navLink>
        <b:navLink value="Link" href="#"></b:navLink>
        <b:navLink value="Linktobeshiftright" href="#"></b:navLink>
    </b:navbarLinks>
</b:navBar>
</h:body>
</html>
```

How to use "pull-right" class in BootsFaces? In their documentation they are using it but the code implementation is not there. [Bootsfaces Navbar Example](http://bootsfaces.net/layout/navbars.jsf;jsessionid=0d_CF0wCslsIWc0LeXfM9FrRhclpL8DUhHJ1k9OF.unknown-host)

The classes they are using are:  `nav navbar-nav pull-right` and `navbar-form navbar-left`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute `pull="right"` of <`b:navbarLinks>`:

```
    <b:navBar brand="Brand" brandHref="#" inverse="true">
      <b:navbarLinks>
        <b:navLink value="Home" href="#"></b:navLink>
        <b:navLink value="Link" href="#"></b:navLink>
        <b:navLink value="Linktobeshiftright" href="#"></b:navLink>
        </b:navbarLinks>
    </b:navBar>
```

If you want to pull an individual `b:navLink` to the right (as your caption implies), you can use the `styleClass` attribute (required BootsFaces 0.7.0 or later).

By the way, you can see the source code of our showcase application at https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFacesWeb.